# Parallelisation in TestNG not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I execute below code, TestNG executes first `MyTest1`, after that it moves to `MyTest2`; it does not executes all 4 classes simultaneously.

```
<suite name="MySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="6">
<test name="MyTest1">
<classes>
<class name="ParllelTestNG.Test1"></class>
<class name="ParllelTestNG.Test2"></class>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="MyTest2">
<classes>
<class name="ParllelTestNG.Test3"></class>
<class name="ParllelTestNG.Test4"></class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Is anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Are MyTest1 & MyTest2 executing in parallel??

This is because you have written parallel=test in below line

```
<suite name="MySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="6">
```

Change parallel="tests" to parallel="classes"